# POSTGRESQL: query that returns a column named valid with a boolean value that tells whether the limited ( name of role ) role password has expired

Tags: sql, postgresql, validation, boolean, roles

Like in Title, I have made so far

```sql
SELECT rolvaliduntil AS "valid" 
FROM pg_authid
WHERE rolname = 'limited'
AND rolvaliduntil > now();
```

I think this is not so hard but I cant find any method.
Here is an image of what I would like to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to the SELECT list:

```
SELECT rolvaliduntil > now() AS "valid" 
FROM pg_authid
WHERE rolname = 'limited'
```